# How can I extract partial strings from a text file using a prefix

Tags: python, string, prefix

I have a text file which contains the following strings in some areas.

```
20170818_141903   Test ! Vdd 3.000000; P: 20.000000;T 20.282000;Part: 0; Baud Rate: 9620.009620; Message: MMS111111110001110100000000000100100000000000000000000000000100010000000000000000000001000000000010000000000001000000100000000010000011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011001001001110001010001000000000111011011001010110000000000000010000001101100000000000000000000011011111010000100111101000000000111111110000111110010110000000010001001101110000101000000000000110010010000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000001000000000010000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010000000000000101010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010100101111111010111000000110100000000101000110000100010101010011010000000000000100010001100000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000SS
```

Unfortunately it is not comma or tab separated, each line is one large string.

I have read in the entire file and am trying to extract everything that is binary data.

This means I want everything inbetween the following characters

> MMS......SS

I also want to extract for example the values after P:, or Vdd: from these areas

```
Vdd 3.000000; P: 20.000000...........................etc
```

What I have done currently:

```
import re

match = re.search(r'\P: (\w+)', LONG_STRING)
        if match:
            print match.group(1)
```

However this doesn't extract the full float, it ignores the decimal place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer v2.0. Overall, this code is pretty stiff and not the clearest one, but currently I can't think of a better solution for the sample you've provided.

```
>>> import re

>>> that_long_row = "20170818_141903   Test ! Vdd 3.000$000; P: 20.000000;T 20.282000;Part: 0; Baud Rate: 9620.009620; Message: MMS111111110001110100000000000100100000000000000000000000000100010000000000000000000001000000000010000000000001000000100000000010000011000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000011001001001110001010001000000000111011011001010110000000000000010000001101100000000000000000000011011111010000100111101000000000111111110000111110010110000000010001001101110000101000000000000110010010000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000001000000000010000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010000000000000101010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010100101111111010111000000110100000000101000110000100010101010011010000000000000100010001100000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000SS "

>>> regex = (r'^'                       # start of a string symbol
         r'.+'                          # escape any character
         r'Vdd '                        # until "Vdd " is reached
         r'(?P<Vdd>[0-9\.]+)'           # select a continuous sequence of numbers and dots folowing that word and assign it to a group "Vdd"
         r'.+'                          # again, skip some more chars
         r'P: '                         # find "P: " word
         r'(?P<P>[0-9\.]+)'             # select a continuous sequence of numbers and dots and assign to a group "P"
         r'.+'                          # the same goes for your byte "Message" between "MMS" and "SS" symbols
         r'MMS'
         r'(?P<Message>[0-1]+)'         # except that it only matches 0 and 1
         r'SS'
         r'.+'                          # as @Evan mentioned, you need this to escape some possible trailing symbols 
         r'$'                           # end of a string symbol
         )

# the same but in a compact form:
>>> regex = r'^.+Vdd (?P<Vdd>[0-9\.]+).+P: (?P<P>[0-9\.]+).+MMS(?P<Message>[0-1]+)SS.+$'

>>> match = re.match(regex, that_long_row)

# matching will form a groupdict that is like a normal dict
# and you can access any matched group value by its name

>>> match.groupdict()
{'Vdd': '3.000', 'P': '20.000000', 'Message': ...
```

Next if you want to parse a file such way, I would create a simple class for holding all the data, type conversion, validation, etc.

```
class Message:
    def __init__(self, Vdd, P, Message):
        self.vdd = float(Vdd)
        self.p = float(P)
        self.text = Message

data = []

with open('yourfile', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       match = re.match(regex, line)
       try:
           data.append(Message(**match.groupdict()))
       except ValueError:
           data.append('CORRUPTED')
```

And so on.

Comment: The string he gave has a space on the end, so you might want to include that in the regex if you want to stick the $ at the end. Also, a nice list comprehension to collect all of these might be useful considering you took the time to write that awesome regex. I don't want to make another answer and have him upvote me when you did all the work.

Comment: how do I find out what all those regex parameters do.  They look horrific.

Comment: 2 @cc6g11, They sure do! I tried to make my answer more clear. Hope this'll help!